# AWS API gateway unreacheable from S3 webpage

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to add a form contact to a AWS S3 static web page with `API Gateway, Lambda and SES`

I checked and followed many guides, so far the API gateway and Lambda together can send email properly.  I even tested successfully with postman APP in my home computer.

I guess the **form webpage script** does not called or it is bad created, please help on check it. The form does not received fail response only reset itself.

This is AWS lambda function

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new AWS.SES();

var RECEIVER = 'xxxxx@gmail.com';
var SENDER = 'xxxxx@gmail.com';

var response = {
 "isBase64Encoded": false,
 "headers": { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
 "statusCode": 200,
 "body": "{\"result\": \"Success.\"}"
 };

exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    console.log('Received event:', event);
    sendEmail(event, function (err, data) {
        context.done(err, null);
    });
};

function sendEmail (event, done) {
    var params = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: [
                RECEIVER
            ]
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Text: {
                    Data: 'name: ' + event.name + '\nphone: ' + event.phone + '\nemail: ' + event.email + '\ndesc: ' + event.desc,
                    Charset: 'UTF-8'
                }
            },
            Subject: {
                Data: 'Website Referral Form: ' + event.name,
                Charset: 'UTF-8'
            }
        },
        Source: SENDER
    };
    ses.sendEmail(params, done);
}
```

the form webpage that it called AWS function is

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form id="contact-form" method="post">
      <h4>Name:</h4>
      <input type="text" style="height:35px;" id="name-input" placeholder="Enter name here" class="form-control" style="width:100%;" /><br/>
      <h4>Phone:</h4>
      <input type="phone" style="height:35px;" id="phone-input" placeholder="Enter phone number" class="form-control" style="width:100%;"/><br/>
      <h4>Email:</h4>
      <input type="email" style="height:35px;" id="email-input" placeholder="Enter email here..." class="form-control" style="width:100%;"/><br/>
      <h4>How can we help you?</h4>
      <textarea id="description-input" rows="3" placeholder="Enter your message..." class="form-control" style="width:100%;"></textarea><br/>
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lc7cVMUAAAAAM1yxf64wrmO8gvi8A1oQ_ead1ys" class="form-control" style="width:100%;"></div>
      <button type="button" onClick="submitToAPI(event)" class="btn btn-lg" style="margin-top:20px;">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>

<script>
function submitToAPI(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var URL = "https://"awsdata".amazonaws.com/probado/sndemail";


       var name = document.getElementById("name-input").value;
       var phone = document.getElementById("phone-input").value;
       var email = document.getElementById("email-input").value;
       var desc = document.getElementById("description-input").value;
       if (name=="" || phone=="" || email=="" || desc=="")
        {
            alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
            return false;
        }

        nameRE = /^[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2,20}[ ]{1}[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2,20}/;
        if(!nameRE.test(name)) {
            alert("Name entered, is not valid");
                return false;
        }

        phoneRE = /^([0|\+[0-9]{1,5})?([7-9][0-9]{9})$/;
        if(!phoneRE.test(phone)) {
                alert("Phone number entered, is not valid");
                return false;
            }

        emailRE = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        if(!emailRE.test(email)) {
            alert("Email Address entered, is not valid");
                return false;
        }
       var data = {
          name : name,
          phone : phone,
          email : email,
          desc : desc
        };

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "<URL for API gateway>");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
            var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            if (xmlhttp.status === 200 ) {
                console.log('successful');
                document.getElementById("contact-form").innerHTML = "<h1>Thank you for your message/feedback<br>our team will get back to you soon!</h1>";
            } else {
                console.log('failed');
            }
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('contact-form').reset();

    } 
</script>

</html>
```

API Gateway CORS

[image]

Comment: If you can hit the API using Postman, then the issue is not Lambda or AWS at all, it is how you are calling the API in the website's JavaScript code. To debug that you first need to open the developer console in the web browser and check for any errors in the Console and Network tabs.

Comment: What does the network trace in your browser show when your browser attempts to call the API?

Comment: The trace is:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://"awsdata".amazonaws.com/probado' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange (contact2.html:66)

Comment: Enable cors on your api gateway console. and also add Access-Control-Allow-Origin in Method response 200

Comment: The API gateway CORS is anable from beginning, I uploaded the picture above in the post; the response is also above and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin = '*'` is set.

Answer (score 0):

The form has to be inside the body and put the script inside the head...

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script> your own script like the one above... </script>
</head>
<body>
<form> user form... </form>
</html>
```